# Chrome auto completando input, autocomplete="off" não funciona

Tags: html5, autocompletar

Ao entrar na pagina de busca "http://conteumahistoria.com/autor/monychan" o input fica se completando sozinho, coloquei autocomplete="off" e não adiantou, o que posso fazer?

```
<input type="text" id="pesquisa" onkeyup="pesquisar()" class="form-control" Autocomplete="off" placeholder="Pesquisa por categoria, nome do livro, descrição do livro, etc">
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar um `autocomplete="random-string"`.